# Need help understanding what co-recursively enumerable means

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, semi-decidability

Lets say I have a set: $ L = \{\langle G \rangle | L(G) = \Sigma^{\star}\}$ and the question asks if it is co-RE. I know that if something is co-RE, it halts on every input not in L but may or may not halt on inputs in L.

So in this case would something "not in L" be nothing?

Comment: What is "co-CE"? Or is it a typo? Also, is $G$ supposed to be a TM here?

Comment: A language is coRE, by definition, if its complement is RE.

Comment: @dkaeae Annoyingly, computability theory has a lot of duplicate terminology: "c.e.," "r.e.," "semidecidable," "recognizable," etc. all mean the same thing (at least in *classical* computability). "Co-c.e." (or "co-CE") means the same thing as "co-r.e."

Answer (score 0):

If you by co-CE mean co-Computably Enumerable, then they are the same.

The field called Recursion Theory is also known as Computation Theory.

You find the same analogy in the classes.  *Recursive* is a different way of calling *Computable*.  A *recursively enumerable* set is a different way of calling *computably enumerable* set.

Answer (score 0):

> So in this case would something "not in L" be nothing?

No. A string $\langle G\rangle$ is not in $L$ means $L(G)\ne \Sigma^*$. Such strings exist of course. For example, if $G$ is a machine that rejects anything, then $L(G)=\emptyset$, thus $\langle G\rangle\notin L$.

Answer (score 0):

A language is said to be co-Turing-Recognisable or co-Recursively Enumerable if it is the complement of a Turing recognisable Language.

We can show that  if a language L is Turing recognisable and it is co-Turing-Recognisable meaning that it's complement is also Turing recognisable then this language is decidable (this may be useful to use as a contradiction ).

So the question is asking you, is the complement of language $L$, say $L'$, Turing recognisable or not?

$L' = \{\langle G\rangle \mid L(G) \neq \Sigma^*\}$ is turing recognisable. How do we know that?

We can construct a TM M to recognise L' ,

M on input < G>:

Construct PDA P from < G>

Generate all strings x in Σ* in lexicographical order

Run x on P

If P rejects any string x accept

If some string x is not accepted by P , then it cannot be generated by G , thus G ≠ Σ* and hence we accept

So , if G ≠ Σ* then we eventually reach a string x not generated by G and eventually accept G , if G = Σ* then we loop

Clearly M recognises L' and hence L' is Turing recognisable , since the complement of L is Turing recognisable , then L is co-turing-recognisable

We can extend this further by proving that L is not Turing recognisable , we know that L' is Turing recognisable , we also know that L is undecidable , if we assume that L is Turing recognisable , then both L and L' are Turing recognisable and hence L is decidable , which is a contradiction , thus L is non-turing recognisable

Note: the terms "Turing recognisable" and "recursively Enumerable" are interchangable.